# Feature detection for svg animation (css @support)

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

Some browsers do not support animated SVG.
 The cleanest workaround I can come up with, would be to perform a '@support (*condition*)' query in the stylesheet, to check if animated svg is supported. If it is I would use my animated svg as the background-image and if not I would use an alternative.
My question is: which expression (or conjunction of expressions) can I use for my condition in order to achieve my goal?
I really would like to avoid both browser detection and the use of javascript.